# Validation for decimal in angular

Tags: angular

I need to validate the rates for decimal. For example, validating the maximum length we use `Validators.maxLength(19)`

Comment: And where is the problem? Or how the community can help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use (max/min) to integer's:

```
[Validators.max(15), Validators.min(6)]
```

if you need validator's more complex's you can user a regular expression (**[Regex](https://regexr.com/)**).

For example:

```
 [Validators.pattern([0-9]{1,}[,]{0,1}[0-9]{0,})]
```

Comment: Hey @Leandro, the problem with your solution is that min() and max() validators do not work for decimal values, only for integers. As far as I could research, there are no validators for min and max decimal values. That's odd...